# How do I get the process handle of a job?

Tags: powershell

Motivation: I am trying to test some process related commands with a simple powershell job. However, all powershell jobs are named "powershell" in the process table. So I need the process handle which I can use to filter `Get-Process` output for.

So, the 'bigger' question may be easier to answer, but as it stands I think I have a solution in place if only I could connect a powershell job to its process ID ("Handle").

How do I obtain the process ID from a powershell job? (this is not the JobID).

```
$job = Start-Job -Name $jobName -ScriptBlock { while($true){sleep -Seconds 1}}
$processes = Get-Process

$jobHandle = ???
$jobProcess = $processes |? {$_.Handle -eq $jobHandle}
```

How do I get the missing information symbolized by '???' ?

---

Dealing with the XY problem and rephrased more generally, if this is impossible because everything is grandfathered into the current powershell session, the bigger question is: how do I create an arbitrarily named or handled process that I can do anything to, from powershell, for testing?

```
# how do I start this code block as an arbitrary named process?
name="test-Get-Foo.1.2"
{
  while($true){
    sleep -Seconds 2
  }
}

# ???

$proc=Get-Process |? {$_.Name -like "test-Get-Foo*"}
```

Comment: In the meantime I am going to start notepad and leverage the process name, but that'll be a bad way to do things if someone who runs my test is using notepad...

Comment: if this is impossible because everything is grandfathered into the current powershell session, the Y question'll be: how do I create an arbitrarily named or handled process that I can do anything to, from powershell, for testing?

Comment: these 2 comments should be part of your question actually. reg. the first 1, the job class doesn't expose the spawned process behind the scenes afaik, so the wait to get the handle would be to check all child jobs of `$PID` before and after spawning your job. reg. the 2nd question, you could use a NamedPipe

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'll factor them in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question, as far as I know the [`Job` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) doesn't expose the underlying process spawned behind the scenes and the way you could get its `ProcessId` would be to do a *before and after* comparison:

```
$before = Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "ParentProcessId = $pid"
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    while ($true) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}
$after = Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "ParentProcessId = $pid"
$process = $after | Where-Object { $_.ProcessId -notin $before.ProcessId }
$jobHandle = $process.ProcessId
```

Regarding the second question, paraphrased:

> How do I create an arbitrarily named or handled process that I can do anything to, from PowerShell, for testing?

For this you can use the [`NamedPipeConnectionInfo` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.namedpipeconnectioninfo?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0). A simple example:

```
try {
    $proc = Start-Process powershell -PassThru -ArgumentList '-WindowStyle', 'Hidden'
    $pipe = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.NamedPipeConnectionInfo]::new($proc.Id)
    $rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($pipe)
    $rs.Open()
    $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({ "Hi there! I'm $PID" })
    $ps.Runspace = $rs
    $ps.Invoke() # `$task = $ps.BeginInvoke()` here for Async
}
finally {
    if ($ps) {
        $ps.Dispose()
    }
    if ($rs) {
        $rs.Dispose()
    }
    # Remove this if you don't want to kill the underlying process :)
    if ($proc) {
        $proc.Kill()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot once I get my test working w/ notepad, thank you!

Comment: @Chris glad it was helpful. you could also consider using runspaces if you don't have a particular need to spawn child processes. runspaces are much more manageable